# I can not get state values from Redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to render my Store using react and redux, but it is not working, this is my App.js and my store.dispatch is here, I have dispatched two expenses

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './Header'
import Router from './reactRouter'
import configS from './stores/configS'
import {addExpense} from './actions/expenseA'
import {setTextFilter, } from './actions/filters'
import  filterV from './selectors/expense'

class App extends Component {


  render() {
    const store = configS()
    store.dispatch(addExpense({
      des: 'water bill',
      amount: 1000,
      createdAt: -21000,
    }))
    store.dispatch(addExpense({
      des: 'light bill',
      amount: 1000,
      createdAt: -21000,
    }))
    store.dispatch(setTextFilter('light'))
    // store.dispatch(startDate('20000'))

    const state = store.getState();
    const vFilters = filterV(state.expenses, state.filters);
    console.log(vFilters);


    return ( 
      <div className = "App" >
      <Header />
      <Router />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is the component that is rendering my store, is saying the array expense array.lenght is 0. ExpenseList.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import ExpenseListItem from './expenseListItem '



const ExpenseList= (props) => (
    <div className="App">
        <h1>Expense List</h1>
        {props.expenses.length}
        {props.expenses.map((expense) => <ExpenseListItem key={expense.id} {...expense} />)}
    </div>
);

const state = (state)=>({
    expenses:state.expenses,
    filters:state.filters
})

 export default connect(state)(ExpenseList)
```

Comment: Your action creators, reducers, store config? Please add those to your question.

Comment: Are you renderering a `<Provider store={store} />` component somewhere in your app?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap Route ([top]parent for f.e. ExpenseList) - if Header doesn't need access to store:

```
return ( 
  <div className = "App" >
    <Header />
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router />
    </Provider>
  </div>
);
```